# PHP testing sub object for null value

Tags: php, json

I have a json object that has been decoded to this:

```
item_json:stdClass Object
(
    [code] => 2013CA
    [SP] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PID] => 1175630
            [FirstName] => Kim
            [LastName] => Kardashian
            [DOB] => 01-02-1978
            [Address1] => 12345 Kardashian Way
            [Address2] => 
            [Address3] => 
            [City] => Hollywood
            [State] => CA
            [Zip] => 90210
            [Country] => US
            [Phone] => 1-210-5551212-
            [Email] => kkardashian@kkardashian.com
            [Info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Declined] => null
                    [NameOnLicense] => KK
                    [State] => CA
                    [License] => 90210
                    [LicenseText] => License Number
                    [TypeID] => 215057
                    [Hours] => 24
                    [Units] => 24
                    [Price] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

How do I test to see if the Info->Declined is null?

I've tried

```
!isset($item_json-SP->Info->Declined)
```

and

```
$item_json-SP->Info->Declined == null
```

but they both fail.

Comment: How did they fail? What did you expect to happen, and what really happened?

Comment: Actually, I went another route, I really needed to check if the NameOnLicense was blank. I'm deleting the question.

Comment: I really wished SO would put a comment notice that identifies the person(s) that downvote a post. Hiding behind your "anonymity" is not cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to test if a value is `NULL` is using the [`is_null()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function. Further note, that the right path to `Declined`, its: `SP->Info->Declined`. Try this:

```
if(is_null($json->SP->Info->Declined)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ($item_json->SP->Info->Declined == null)
```

You have an error here $item_json-SP   it is not a this operator, you have syntax error there, there is inbuilt in PHP to check null values

```
if(is_null($json->SP->Info->Declined)) {
}
```